# User input in terminal not accepted while debugging C++ in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cin, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a program in C++, using VScode, which requires input from the user(using `cin`), then uses this value elsewhere in the program.

When I compile and run the code, everything works fine, but when I run the debugger (I'm using Microsoft C++ compiler and debugger cl.exe, not g++ and gdb), the program runs until the `cin` command and then stops to get the value from the user.

When I try to type a value in the debug console, nothing happens, and the execution remains paused. (In the picture attached, I tried to enter the number 5 three times, but it wasn't working.)

[image: 1]

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this issue so can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how your program output ended up in the debug console. All program input/output should go to the terminal window, not to the debug console window. The latter is for interacting with the debugger itself. Perhaps it's the peculiarity of Microsoft debugger.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. nope, in VS Code the Terminal window is for a helper shell (powershell). Program output goes to the Debug Console window.

Comment: @rustyx This is absolutely not what I experience with my VS  Code installation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It must be some setting then, like `"externalConsole": true` in the launch configuration (although that works differently).

Comment: @rustyx I only have a bare minimum configuration, certainly no exotic settings like this one.